# Is there uncertainity of position of the perfectly homogenous radiating body?

Tags: astronomy, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, error-analysis, luminosity

I heard the standard interpretation of Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle: Just the measurement affects the position of the body because always you want to see a body (=to measure the position), you need a light - and only the fact that photons that strike the surface of that radiating body have momentum mean that the position of the radiating body isn't certain (even theoretically) only because of your measuring - and therefore the uncertainty in position will always be non-zero.

However, if we knew that a photon that came to us, comes from a perfectly homogeneous radiating body, we also know that the recoil, which gives photon after emitting always corresponds to a photon equally strong on the other side of the radiating body.

Of course, the body can not perfectly homogeneously radiate and moreover there is no way we could get an information that the body perfectly homogeneously radiate, but if it all would possible, where would the position uncertainty disappear?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. All measurements have some uncertainty associated with them. For example, if it is a faint source, there is Poisson noise.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at. A body may emit radiation isotropically (equally in all directions) on _average_  but emission of a photon on one side will not happen at the same time as emission of a photon on the other side. As a result the radiating body will execute a random walk which _on average_ will return it to the starting point, but there will be still be an uncertainty in its position - the average may be zero, but the standard deviation will not be.

Comment: The position uncertainty of the radiating body would lie in the uncertainty of the photons detected.

Comment: @G.Paily Oh, that (what you´re describing) wouldn´t be perfect isotropic radiation (You says this mean that radiation is equall in all directions - so there for there have to be a photon apart the photon we´ve seen) What happend if we really see perfectly isotropic radiating body?

Comment: @DirkBruere Yes, you should be right if there would be some else reason to have uncertainity here, but it seems there is NO reason not to detect the photon perfectly (the basic reason should be affecting of the radiating body, but in this case this cannot be true)

Comment: @physicsphile I asked for this: I think the explanation I used is not correct. I KNOW there is always some error associated with them but this cause is the only one I don´t why should be uncertainity here. So please, explain me. Thank you.

Comment: Well, spontaneous emission of radiation is a random/probabilistic process. I don't know if it is possible to have a perfectly isotropic radiating body. Plus fixing the polarization direction would probably break the spherical symmetry, to some degree.

Comment: @G.Paily Ok, but is there some problem only related with detection?

Answer (score 2):

This question confuses two frameworks, the classical thermodynamic one with the quantum mechanical one.

A perfectly homogenous radiating body belongs to classical thermodynamics.

Photons belong to quantum mechanics, as well as the uncertainty principle.

Lets look at the problem classically. Electromagnetic radiation is continuous from a classical body and therefore theoretically  there is no uncertainty other than the measurement uncertainty given by the method of determining the position of the body, since, as you say, at the same time radiation is leaving equally and oppositely.

The problem quantum mechanically can only be looked at quantum mechanical dimensions, so the body should have nanometer size and smaller . Let us assume a crystal for simplicity, because it has a coherent wave function, and no input energy is keeping it in equilibrium with the environment. The crystal wave function has higher  energy levels the higher the temperature, and empty levels below to which it can relax radiating a photon. In these dimensions the quantization of radiation is relevant. There will be a time constant for a photon to be released because the body fell from a higher vibrational level to a lower one, and this will not be compensated at the same delta(t) by an equal and opposite photon in the other direction, because photon emissions are random depending on the wavefunction of the crystal . whose square has the probabilities of emission.

So in the quantum mechanical frame the "opposite" emission of photons cannot hold in a delta(t) so the photon momentum will impose an indeterminacy, assuming the center of the nano crustal to begin at (0,0,0). Using the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), the momentum of the photon is

[image: photon momentum]

the uncertainty in momentum is proportional  is h*delta(lamda)/lamdda^2 and this will set the uncertainty in  position  x ,that cannot  be known even in theory. This ends up to

delta(lamda)*x> lamda^2 ,  x>lamda

so the position x  cannot be known better than the wavelength of the emitted photon.

This intrinsic quantum mechanical bound  of order of nanometers can never be reached in accuracy when measuring the position of a classical body, more so of an astronomical size body. It is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you very much. But isn't it only our fall that we can't measure at the quantum level the macroscopic systems?

Comment: Yes, the Heisenberg uncertainty is always satisfied for macroscopic systems , because h*nu, the energy of a single photon, is so low since h is such a small number for  macroscopic systems which are composed by ~ 10^23 , atoms/molecules (avogadro constant) that classical  mechanics and thermodynamics describe the systems.

Comment: @annav And what causes that crystal's wave function is random (or what makes it random)? I thought that this is proven by the Uncertainity principle.

Comment: @Probably The crystal is not random. It is controlled by very precise quantum mechanical functions that give the probability for finding the atoms at specific locations. The Heisenberg uncertainty is an over all tool that reflects the intrinsic structure of the operator functions that are involved in the generation of the state function whose square gives the probabilities. A calculational tool, imo.

Comment: @annav Could you please explain me it a little bit deeper (axiom by axiom)? Why is the crystal position given by this wave function? The model I had known before was, as writes foggy, the easy pop-sci interpretation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Probably Physics does not have axioms. Axioms belong to mathematics. Physics uses mathematics  and has postulates, which relate measurable quantities to the output of mathematical operations. Quantum mechanics is the regime of photons, there are no photons in classical physics. In classical physics one can postulate a body radiating classical electromagnetic radiation symmetrically and thus overall not moving. When one goes to a one photon at a time radiation then it is the quantum regime where the Heisenberg principle applies. Crystals are macroscopic manifestation of the underlying qm state

Comment: continued: and can be described with a QM wavefunction.

Comment: But why the Heisenberg principle applies here? I know that the imagination of the perfectly homogenous body is absurd but if it would be true, there would be a dependence on symmetry as the body went closer to this state. From Gamow I know the Heisenberg principle foggy describes in the first paragraph. Is it correct? There isn't as significant influence of the wave/particle dilema in this model. btw every scientific thesis has to be based on some axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics).

Comment: They are not axioms, they are postulates. Axioms mean that from a few mathematical axioms all the theory can be derived. The postulates are not mathematical, they are statements that connect a coherent mathematical model to data. The HUP applies to everything , except h_bar is so small that it is always satisfied in classical situations where we can measure, within our errors. Only when single particles or coherent quantum mechanical states are involved (crystal) the HUP comes into play.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you so long, but your fourth sentence is probably not completed. How can HUP not apply for a constant? Please, answer me one more time, is the model foggy describes in the first paragraph valid? If so, I see know reason for uncertainity in the wave function.

Comment: @Probably The model is wrong used for photons, as photons are elementary particles with quantum mechanical attributes and the way the classical electromagnetic field that he is talking about is being built up by photons is complicated, zillions of photons contribute to the classical electromagnetic wave. The radiation of one photon is independent from any other so there will be no balance that he proposes. Due to the energy and momentum  taken away by a single photon the center of mass of the body will move, and I have tried to estimate the dimensions of this motion using the HUP.

Comment: @anna v Ok, so what determines any randomness here? Why can't we talk about photons here? What's wrong with photons (they are more precise, aren't they)?

Comment: @Probably No; photons, as all elementary particles, are not more precise. There is a probability in their generation that is essentially controlled by the wavefunction describing the process and can only be studied cumulatively, as probability distributions. An individual photon can be considered random with respect to another individual photon, unless very specific conditions obtain, as in lasers.

Comment: Ok, if the randomness is caused only by this wave function (and not with detection), how did we get this random (and precise at once) wave function?

Comment: @Probably By solving the schrodinger equation imposing the boundary conditions of the situation under study one gets the specific wave function. The square of the wave function will give the probability of finding that a photon has been  emitted in the (r,theta,phi) vector direction.